# How to get count of elements that do have string value one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How to get the count of elements present in array that contains only string @"one".

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"one",@"one",@"two",@"one",@"five",@"one",nil];
```

How to get the count of array which contains one in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Count the number of times an object occurs in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833992/objective-c-count-the-number-of-times-an-object-occurs-in-an-array)

Comment: just use NSPredicate, simple and optimized way...

Comment: Haven't tried it, but Key-value-coding and its special keys (@count etc.) might work for this...?

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to go:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"one",@"one",@"two",@"one",@"five",@"one",nil];
```

**Use blocks:**

```
NSInteger occurrenceCount = [[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {return [obj isEqual:@"one"];}] count];
```

**Use loop:**

```
int occurrenceCount = 0;
for(NSString *str in array){
    occurrenceCount += ([string isEqualToString:@"one"]?1:0);
}
```

**Use `NSCountedSet`:**

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSLog(@"Occurrences of one: %u", [countedSet countForObject:@"one"]);
```

**Use NSPredicate:**(as EridB suggested)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@",
                          @"one"];

NSInteger occurrenceCount = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;
```

Check answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833992/objective-c-count-the-number-of-times-an-object-occurs-in-an-array) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution from the ones mentioned

```
// Query to find elements which match 'one'
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@",
                          @"one"];

// Use the above predicate on your array
// The result will be a `NSArray` so from there we count the elements on this array
NSInteger count = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;

// Prints out number of elements
NSLog(@"%li", (long)count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one",@"one",@"two",@"one",@"five",@"one"];
    NSPredicate *searchCountString= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@",@"one"];
    NSInteger count = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchCountString].count;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)count);
```